# Mapping language specific chars with modifiers in ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I am having a difficult time mapping some of my language specific keys (danish keys æøå) in ideavim. It works fine when i map without modifies eg. `nmap æ /` but when I try to map with alt eg. `nmap <M-æ> {` that does not get picked up. I can use Ctrl+V to see literals for remapping in proper vim, but not ideavim.

EDIT: I tried to use ctrl+q in insert mode, which works (when you set vim as handler in insertmode):

```
sethandler <C-q> n-v:ide i:vim
inoremap <C-q> {
```

But the same trick does not work for æ, so I am no further with that part.

```
sethandler <C-æ> n-v:ide i:vim
inoremap <C-æ> {
```

Comment: I have not used ideavim.  In Vim, in normal mode, typing `ga` will give the ASCII / Unicode number of the character under the cursor is, displayed in the status line.  Maybe that is useful for "seeing what vim 'sees'"?

Comment: @m_mlvx it does actually. æ gives "VIM - <æ> 230, Hex e6, Oct 346, Digr ae". I'm not sure how it can help mapping, but it is interesting, thanks :)

Comment: I do not know the Danish keyboard; but Vim has "digraphs" ready, which you use by 'ctrl-k' then the two keys.  For example, `<C-k>14` gives ¼.  You can see a list in Vim by `:dig`  For me on the English keyboard, while in Insert Mode, I can type `<C-k>ae` to get æ or `<C-k>AE` to get Æ.  I don't know if that can solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Type `ga` when the cursor is above a character to get information about that character.

I got the following values (with a norwegian locale, yours may differ):

```
æ => 230
ø => 248
å => 229
```

You can then make remappings like this:

```
inoremap <Char-248> {
inoremap <Char-230> }
```